# Why don't modern Romance languages have the verb "to stand"?

Tags: semantics, verbs, romance-languages

I noticed that modern Romance languages don't have a specific word for the verb "to stand", or - you could say - don't consider the notion of standing to be a verb.

For example, in Spanish - you can say *pararse*, which means to stop yourself (from moving). Or you can say *levantarse*, which means to raise yourself (to a standing position). You can also say *estar a pie* which mean being on your feet.

I checked and it seems to also be the case for French and Italian.

Other languages do have a special word. English and German for example - (German Stehen). Hebrew has la'amod (לעמוד) which has the same root as the noun pillar (amud - עמוד). Not sure about other languages though.

Comment: *stāre* is ultimately cognate with *stand*.  But *stand* in Romance languages is generally seen as a state, not an action (cf. *sit*).  To *stand **up*** (or to *sit **down***) however, is definitely an action and has plenty of options — *levantar(se)*, *poner(se) de pie*, *erguir(se)* in Spanish, for instance.

Comment: [_`ST-`_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/st.pdf) goes back [a ***long*** way in Indo-European](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf).

Comment: Why does English not have a word for "be (somewhere)" as opposed to "be (something)"? Because that's the way English is. That's usually the only answer to "why" questions about language.

Comment: Maybe this is a naive answer to the "why", but I'd say that since *stāre* has the same etymology as *stand* and it originally also meant "stand", then when *stāre*'s meaning shifted towards the modern Romance one, Romance was left without a verb for "stand". Now, of course it could have created or borrowed a new word for it, but likely before that happened, expressions like "estar de pie" or "stare in piedi" had already taken hold, and there was no perceived need to replace them with something briefer partly because they fit so well together with other uses of "stare" that were now common.

Comment: @LjL- sounds plausible. Post it as an answer.

Comment: I think it's also very interesting, that the notion of standing became related to impermanent being. Maybe because my mother tongue is Hebrew, standing for me can also be permanent. And I guess it's the same for native English speakers.

Comment: DavidRefaeli: In the Iberian languages which distinguish *((e)s)tar* from *ser*, the former doesn't represent impermanence, rather state (which as an English word also derives from the same word).  You are standing, or sitting, or laying, etc, all of which are seen as separate states (cf. being married/single/engaged/widowed). Permanence isn't part of the deciding factor.

Comment: I'm not able to make an answer of it, but suppose taboo given a sense "have a hard-on", a by sense of Ger *stehen*, *Ständer*; cp En *stud*, "sexually attractive male", *sturdy, duro-* (cp *steady*), *stick* (cp *dick*?) and *to stick*, Ger *stochern, stecken*; further Ger *steigen*, *aufsteigen* (escalate, ascend),  *aufstehen* (to get up), which could formaly correspond to *stay* either way. I mean, perhaps you are aware of any comparable Spanish euphemisms. I can only note Ita *stronzo* (vs Ger *strotzen*?). By the way, is *estar* comparable to *be going*?

Comment: @vectory you provide valuable insight sometimes but some other times I really wonder what the *heck* is on your mind. Maybe you're providing valuable insight the rest of the time too and I'm just too dumb to follow...

Comment: @DavidRefaeli I'm not sure I feel comfortable with posting it as an answer, since it's basically a guess... which does seem plausible to me (and I speak one of the Romance languages involved), but considering plausible is not *knowing*.

Comment: @LjL I'm overwhelmed by the material to compare and seek refuge in the absurd. There's a non-obscene sense in *good standing* (righteous, upright) which is similar. Indeed, *auf eigenen Beinen stehen* means independence, be reliable. Though there's also *bei Fuß* (at heel; command to dogs), i.e. *stop, stand*, not quite *sit*! Neither in pre- nor suffix are *estar* and *stand* cognate, is it?

Comment: @user0721090601 I think you're mistaken. The main difference between ser and estar are that ser is permanent and estar is impermanent. You can find references to this in many sites, including SpanishDict, and you can also see it from the usage of the language itself. With some "exceptions"  like with death, when you say esta muerto, but this is a tongue-in-cheek way to express the belief that death is not permanent, or with permanent locations (el EEUU esta en Norteamérica).

Comment: @DavidRefaeli I have a PhD in Spanish and Portuguese, I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli that's right, in English we can describe a statue or a building as "standing" in a location. For example, "The Statue of Liberty stands in New York Harbor.".

Comment: @user0721090601 Death its not an exception, its a rule, Está vivo
Está muerto
Está feliz
Está triste
The phrase is "Estados Unidos está en Norteamérica" The United States is a country, its in singular, not in plural, no matter if the name talks about the states, which is plural, here there are some examples
Soy Carlos (Im Carlos)
Soy un un buen amigo (Im a good friend)
Estoy bien (Im fine)
¿Cómo estás? (How are you?, asking about his situation)
¿Cómo eres? (How are you?, asking about his way to be)
Tengo hambre (Im hungry)
Eres bastante desagradable (You are pretty mean)
Estados Unidos está en

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to sum up what was said in the comments and maybe offer some conjecture, though I don't think it's possible to answer this question with great certainty.

Latin did originally have a verb meaning 'to stand': *stāre*. Already in the Classical period, this verb also had the meaning 'to stay'.

It's actually not the case that this verb was lost (in this meaning) in all Romance languages: it's preserved in the Eastern Romance languages, e.g. Romanian *a sta* 'to stay, remain, *stand*, sit'.

In the Italo-Western Romance, though, the 'stand' meaning was lost. It's probably the case that initially the 'stay' meaning gained primacy, and that's the case still in Italian (*stare* 'to stay, remain'); in Gallo-Romance and Ibero-Romance languages, it additionally came to mean 'to be', to the point that this is now its primary meaning (French *être*, Spanish &c. *estar*; the full paradigms are suppletive, but that's common). The Gallo-Romance/Ibero-Romance shift may have been more dramatic than the Italian one because those areas had more people learning Latin as a second language, or at least in closer contact with other languages.

These developments reflect what seems to be a general move in (SAE?) Indo-European languages away from *stative* verbs and towards *dynamic* verbs: verbs are felt as being for expressing carrying out an action, not being in a state. The 'stand' meaning of *stāre* was stative (it meant 'to be in a standing position', not 'to stand up'), the 'stay' meaning is dynamic ('carrying out the act of staying'); the 'to be' meaning is stative, but the merger with *esse* still reduces the total number of stative verbs in the language. Proto-Indo-European had a lot of stative verbs, and a lot of these still remain in the daughter languages, but it's not surprising to see their meanings shift to become (more) dynamic (in English a lot of stative verbs are now also inchoative: 'to stand' can also mean 'to enter a standing position'), to see them merge with other stative verbs, or not to see replacements being coined when one is lost.